# How to add file size next to the files name?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to export all files according to their extensions and add the size next to them.

```
import glob2
ext = raw_input("extension:")
ext = "*." + ext
print glob2.glob(ext)
```

How can I add the file size to the list?

Answer (score -2):

Use `os.stat()` to find out file metadata (size, date created, etc). It's not clear to me what you mean by *next to them* so this code produces a list of tuples, [(filename,filesize), ... ].

```
import glob2 
import os
ext = raw_input("extension:") 
ext = "*." + ext 
filenames = glob2.glob(ext)
filenames_with_sizes = [(filename, os.stat(filename).st_size) for filename in filenames]
print filenames_with_sizes
```

If you want a pretty list that is nice to print but not amenable to computation then you can do

```
filenames_with_sizes = ["%-40.40s %d" % (filename, os.stat(filename).st_size) for filename in filenames]
```